# Position of 在 电脑上 in "他常练习在电脑上用汉语写东西"

Tags: sentence-structure

My Chinese text has this sentence.

> 他常练习在电脑上用汉语写东西.

As I think, 在电脑上 indicates the "place" that all actions ("练习","用汉语写东西") take place. So what I do not understand is, **why 在电脑上 (PLACE) is put after 练习 (VERB).** It should have been put after 常.

Please explain to me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

她写东西。
她用汉语写东西。
她练习用汉语写东西。
她用汉语练习写东西。
她在电脑上用汉语练习写东西。
她用汉语在电脑上练习写东西。
她常用汉语在电脑上练习写东西。
她常在电脑上用汉语练习写东西。

I think I covered all the options!

Answer (score 1):

> In "他常**在电脑上练习**用汉语写东西",  the location '电脑上' is placed before the verb '练习'
>
> 他常 (he often)
>
> 在电脑上(on computer) -- **location**
>
> 练习 practice -- **verb**
>
> 用汉语写东西 -- relative clause

~

> In "他常练习**在电脑上用汉语写东西**" ,  the location '电脑上' is placed before the verb phrase '用汉语写东西'
>
> 他常(**he often**)
>
> 练习 (*verb*)
>
> 在电脑上用汉语写东西 -- relative clause

~

> *在电脑上 **location***
>
> *用汉语写东西 -- **verb phrase** (the verb is 写)*

Both sentences mean "He often practices writing in Chinese on a computer". The difference is in the first sentence the location '在电脑上' is a relative phrase for the main verb '练习' (*在电脑上练习*) ; and in the second sentence, the location '在电脑上' is a relative phrase for the verb in the relative clause '用汉语写东西' (*在电脑上用汉语写东西*)

Comment: So, if the predicate has 2 more actions, for example, I can write in 2 ways, right?
E.g: 我学 /在晚饭/ 用筷子/ 吃中国菜。
       我 /在晚饭/ 学 / 用筷子/ 吃中国菜。

Comment: 在晚饭(时) is a description of "time"  And yes, you can write "我学习 /在晚饭时/ / 用筷子/ 吃中国菜。(I learn  to use chopsticks to eat Chinese food in dinner time) or " 我 /在晚饭时/ 学习/ 用筷子/ 吃中国菜 (I, in dinner time, learn to use chopsticks to eat Chinese food)

Comment: thank you so much :D

Comment: As long as the 'location before verb rule' are complied. " 他常练习在电脑上" would be ungrammatical; "他常用汉语写东西在电脑上" would be grammatical, but 电脑 in 写东西在电脑上 is not a location but an object